# Set cookie and then refresh page, PHP

Tags: php, cookies

I'm sure this topic had been addressed before, but I can't seem to find an adequate solution to my problem, which I'm sure is not unique.

So I get that you can't set a cookie and expect to use without refreshing the page. So I'm wondering what my options are.

I have a simple set of links that change the language on the page by setting a cookie to that user's language preference. I need to detect that cookie to assign a variable so that I can then change the page output to the designated language.

So, when the button is pressed, it sends a get variable to the URL bar, which then sets the cookie. After I refresh the page, I get what I want.

Basically, I need to pass the GET variable and then refresh the page. How can I do this?

my php code:

```
// if someone is trying to change the language
if(isset($_GET['lang']))
{
    // change the cookie value to that language
    $value = $_GET['lang'];
}
// elseif they are not trying to change the language, and a cookie is already set
elseif(isset($_COOKIE['language_pref']))
{
    // maintain the value of the language set in the cookie
    $value = $_COOKIE['language_pref'];
}
// if get nor cookie is set
else
{
    // set default language to english
    $value = 'en_US';
}
$name = 'language_pref';
// cookie expires in 2 years
$expireDate = time() + (2 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60);
$path = '/';
$domain = 'example.com';
$secure = false; //only transmit the cookie if a HTTPS connection is established
$httponly = true; //make cookie available only for the HTTP protocol (and not for JavaScript)
setcookie( $name, $value, $expireDate, $path, $domain, $secure, $httponly);
```

My HTML:

```
<a href="?lang=zh_CN">ZH</a>
<a href="?lang=en_US">EN</a>
```

Comment: You don’t need a refresh – the information, which language to display has already been passed to you via URL parameter.

Comment: @CBroe I need all of the content that was on the page to change to a different language, so I definitely need a page refresh.

Comment: _“I need all of the content that was on the page”_ – why don’t you _have_ it already?

Comment: @CBroe so I've updated the post to include my php

Comment: And so where is the actual problem now? After that code, you know which language the user wants – either because they requested it explicitly via GET parameter, or implicitly via cookie value … and after that you continue with your normal request processing, by serving the content in the requested language. You are making up a problem here that does not really exist.

Comment: @CBroe so the user clicks an href that gives the url bar a ?lang=xx, that doesn't refresh the page, it just sets the cookie, and my content is already there

Comment: Why would that not refresh the page? Well it wouldn’t perhaps if you _only_ set the cookie, and don’t deliver any actual content after it (but that should require an additional 204 status code).

Comment: @CBroe I added my buttons so you could see them

Comment: So the address of the page you are on did not have any GET parameters before, was just something like `foo.htm` or `bar.php`? If so, this would definitively lead to the browser loading a new resource. If it _had_ GET parameters however, then you are overwriting those here – then you should build the address dynamically by taking the existing GET parameters and _adding_ the one for the language.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here is what your page looks like:

```
> Read cookie and get the language
> Read GET variable and SET COOKIE
> Print out stuff in their language
```

You are simply doing things in the wrong order. If you do things in this order:

```
> Read GET variable and SET COOKIE
> Read cookie and get the language
> Print out stuff in their language
```

You'll already have the right language and have no need to refresh the page.

Comment: so I've added my php to the post -- do you not think I am following your order?

Answer (score 0):

I think all you are missing is the button that links to the url that contains this php.

If your button however you have implemented it has a href containing the url to this page, then when you click on it, you will have refreshed the page and read the contents of the cookie into $value.

try closing the php tags and then adding :

```
<a href='PAGE_URL_HERE'>button</a>
```

Comment: so the button is within a nav that exists on every page of the site, so I need to reload the current page. unfortunately, when I use some js to reload the current page, it keeps adding on the get variables, so if someone clicks ?lang='cats', and it reloads with ?lang='cats' and then they change the language again, i get ?lang='cats'?land='dogs', which is not a recognized cookie.

Comment: All you need is 2 links with the href's containing "PAGE_URL?lang=cats" and "PAGE_URL?lang=dogs". Clicking on them will set it to one or the other.

Comment: WTF has JS got to do with this? Just make that link so that on every page it links _to that same page_, only with the GET parameter for the language added.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a php header or JavaScript included in the else component of your code that only gets executed if the statement meets all of your conditions because all you want is to refresh the page after the cookie is set and or read

Answer (score 0):

cleared it up with this php, which allows me to translate the current page according to the get variable and all later pages with the stored cookie

```
if(isset($value))
{
    $language = $value;

}
else
{
    $language = $_COOKIE['language_pref'];
}
```